# Why does my child theme break my Divi website's header menu?

Tags: wordpress-theming, divi-theme

When I activate my child theme, the header menu on my website displays a combination of all header and footer menu items plus others that aren't on any menu. I was able to activate the same child theme on a staging site of my website where the menus all displayed properly. I even tried activating the child theme on the live site without any files in the child theme folder. Even without any files in there, the problem still happened. Re-activating the main divi theme solves the problem, but obviously means I can't have a child-theme.

I've tried the usual google search avenues for this problem but haven't found anything or anyone with the same problem. Has anyone here had this kind of problem with divi or a different theme before and may I ask what you did to solve it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as explained in the link provided by @alf0282, after installing the child theme, selecting the menus in the “Appearance” -> “Menus” -> “Manage locations” is required.

```
wp-admin/nav-menus.php?action=locations
```